# Displaying an InfoMaker sub report

Tags: infomaker

I need to display an InfoMaker sub report even when there is no data. The idea is for my customer, who would like to see the header even if there is no data so that they can see that the section has no data. If I hard code the header into the main report, the sub report directly above the "empty" sub report could bleed over and display on top of the hard coded header.

I could set the "Visible" property, but I need the dynamic placement of the header to avoid being overwritten by the preceding (above) sub report.

If any further information is required, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a decode statement to add a "dummy" value if there are no results.

```
decode(column, data_you_expect, true_result, false_result)
```